# Meaning of "ad" in a pharmaceutical patent: "Acetic acid ad pH 5.0"

Tags: terminology

Can the abbreviation "ad" mean "up to" in pharmacology? I saw a translator translate the Russian line "до pH 5.0" ("pH level up to 5.0") in a table describing the composition of a drug product as "ad pH 5.0". The meaning of the Russian record was "the content of the excipient in the product may be as high as to bring the product's pH to 5.0, but not higher".

I looked up [a list of pharma abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_abbreviations_used_in_medical_prescriptions), and "ad" there does not have the meaning "up to".

I googled and [found this on Google Patents](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2172664C?cl=en):

> Ammonium acetate 0.77 mg Sodium chloride 7.21 mg Benzyl alcohol 10.0 mg Polysorbate 80 0.2 mg Acetic acid **ad** pH 5.0 0.1 q,s, NaOH 0.1 N ad pH 5.0 0.1 q,s, Water for injection ad 1.0 ml

But this is unlikely to mean "up to", yes? I wonder what the meaning is there.

To be on the safe side, I used "up to" in my translation, but now I'm curious.

Comment: I suggest not to ask about things easily found in dictionaries, like http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ad

Comment: @Mithoron - I was not sure that  it was used as "up to" in this particular situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely yes. In latin,(1) *ad* means *"to, towards, until"*, like in *"ad libitum"* (aka *ad lib*) which means *"keep going until I am satisfied"*, or *"ad nauseam"*.

(1) Pharmaceuticals very often use latin.

Comment: Ad hoc... for this

Comment: Nice! I did not even think about that one :-)